# Tansition from ejml to library with sparse matrices

Tags: java, sparse-matrix, ejml

How can i easily make a transition from ejml to another library that supports sparse matrices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to look at [la4j (Linear Algebra for Java)](http://la4j.org). This library supports sparse entries. I am not sure about easy transition from EJML to la4j, since these library has a different API. But, I belive it should be possible.

The best way to get last version of la4j - use its [GitHub page](https://github.com/vkostyukov/la4j).

Answer (score 0):

EJML now has support for [sparse matrices](https://ejml.org/wiki/index.php?title=Example_Sparse_Matrices). As of it's writing it supports most of the standard operations. For decompositions it supports LU, Cholesky, and QR.